# Install Ubuntu from one drive to the other?

Tags: system-installation

I have only two drives. One of them contains my Ubuntu system that I use at this very moment. I want to install a fresh system on another empty drive. I don't have USBs or CDs at my disposal. Is there a way to install it from a system that I'm using?

Comment: You can download a Ubuntu ISO and have it stored on a disk partition on your existing system, then modify your grub system to allow booting that ISO, which can be used to install to another drive, or another partition on the same drive.  *I did this on a system I wanted to still use for Quality Assurance testing when the device no longer had any working USB drives; I didn't want to use DVDs*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [20.04 booting .iso from GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu)

Comment: I don't really understand. I wish it had a step-by-step tutorial. I don't even know what grub is

Comment: Will your computer boot in UEFI mode? If so create a 10GB NTFS partition on it then extract the Ubuntu ISO to that. When booting select the new partition. You will then be able to install Ubuntu to the new disk. See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1459018/43926